# iptables forward traffic coming from openvpn tunnel to lan

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat

Below is the network topology:

```
------------------------ 123.45.67.89 (WAN)      ----------------------
|    pfSense           |-------------------------|     Public client  |
------------------------                         ----------------------
         | 10.1.1.1 (tun)
         |
         |
         | 10.1.1.2 (tun)
----------------------- 192.168.0.2 (LAN)   192.168.0.3 (LAN)----------------
|       RPi           | -------------------------------------|  VNC Server  | 
-----------------------                                      ----------------
```

**Scenario:**

1. Public client accesses pfSense on WAN ip and port 5900
2. Traffic is forwarded by pfSense to OpenVPN ip 10.1.1.2:5900 (RPi)
3. RPi performs SNAT and DNAT and forwards to 192.168.0.3:5900 (VNC Server)
4. VNC Server responds to Source IP, i.e. 192.168.0.2
5. **PROBLEM:** Response is not forwarded to pfSense by RPi, unless I set it up so that all traffic goes through tun (using routes). However, I would like only the responses from VNC Server, related to VNC traffic to go through tun interface.

Below is the iptables setup on RPi

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:5900:5905 to:192.168.0.3:5900-5905

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:5900:5905 to:192.168.0.2

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I though about puting ip 10.1.1.2 in SNAT but since VNC Server does not know how to route this subnet, I ended up with asymmetric routing.

Below is the **not working** routing table:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         speedport-entry 0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

Below is the **working** routing table (all traffic goes through tun):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         speedport-entry 0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
static.89.67.45 speedport-entry 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.1.1.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

**Question:** 
How do I forward traffic coming to 192.168.0.2 from VNC server to tun ?

Thank you

Comment: You have a typo in the `DNAT` rule: `dpts:9500:9505` instead of `dpts:5900:5905`.

Comment: Thank you - you are right. Unfortunately, this was not the problem. I found the resolution and I am posting it now. I will edit the question, correcting the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tcpdump` on RPi I managed to understand the problem better and solve it. I am posting here the solution for anyone who may face the same issue.

**Solution**
To achieve what I wanted, I had to perform SNAT on pfSense for traffic going out of OpenVPN interface for the ports used for VNC.

**Explanation**
I realized using `tcpdump`, that the source address of the packets going to VNC Server was the IP address of the *Public Client* (internet IP address). Therefore, when the RPi received the response from VNC server, it was trying to route the traffic to the *Public Client's* IP address (an internet IP address). The route to this public IP, was through the LAN Gateway (i.e. not through the tunnel).

By performing SNAT on pfSense and replacing the Public Client's IP address (in the source) to the pfSense VPN address, the RPi now knows where to send the responses to (to pfSense through the tunnel).

Hope it helps.